# How can I slice a string 'rnhM' from the variable "Mahendra" in reverse order?

Tags: python, string

Q.1 How can I slice a string `'rnhM'` from a variable with value `"Mahendra"`. I can get it in normal order but not in reverse order.

```py
person = "Mahendra"`
person[::2]
```

which gave me output `'Mhnr'`

Q.2 .Given two lists of equal size create a list such that it shows the element from both lists in the pair `(i, i^2)`?

*take i in range 10*

Comment: if you got the answer, please accept it so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to first question:

```
name = "Mahendra"
print(name[::2][::-1])
or 
print(name[::-1][1::2])
```

you can't use name[::-2] because it will always take last char into account and will return you 'adea'

Answer to second question:

```
print([(i,i**2) for i in range(5)]+ [(i,i**2) for i in range(5)])
```